# Add default start and end date to crystal report parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report where i have a date parameter called range that i want to default the min and maxdate values. So in the edit parameter dialog under value options section there are options for "start" and "end" which i want to be mindate and maxdate respectively. The problem i am trying to solve is i want all records to return if the user does not enter a value for the range. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance for any advice.

I am running latest version of crystal reports

[image]

Comment: If you are going to downvote please comment as to why. This is a legit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way I think is of using 2 parameters instead of one, That is one parameter for start date and other for End Date.

Add a default value `None` for both and if user doesn't want to select any value then ask to select `None`

Now change your record selection formula as

```
if {?start date} = "None" and {?End date} = "None"
then
//Don't pass any date filter
else
//Add date filter as per parameter selection
```

Comment: This is what i ended up doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easy way could be to just enter min and max dates manually and make the parameter not optional.

A more elegant way is to check whether the parameter has a value and only filter your records if it has. Put something like the below in your record selection formula:

`if hasvalue({?range}) then {yourdatefield} in {?range} else true`

If the parameter `range` has a value then it is used as filter. If it hasn't a value the term will evaluate to `true` meaning no records will be filtered.

Comment: So when you say enter min/max dates manually that is what i am trying to do. Is there a keyword in crystal like in other languages like mindate/maxdate. In other words i am trying to put in that syntax in the fields circled in screenshot.

Comment: @Maxqueue There is no keyword for a max/mindate that I am aware of. You have to enter literal values.

Comment: That is what i was afraid of. Thanks for looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible make the parameter as optional. By default it will bring all the data, if user not select any thing.

Comment: Not true for a range. Setting it to optional does not work.